# Loop through array checking for indexOf's more simple?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, jscript

Okay, like the title says. I have a array looking like this:

```
var hiTriggers = new Array();
hiTriggers = ["hi", "hai", "hello"];
```

And I'd like to check through it if it finds either of those. I can already achieve this by doing the following:

```
if(message.indexOf("hi") >= 0) {
   // do whatever here!
}
```

But I'm looking for an more efficient way rather than doing 100 if() checks. Such as loop through an array with the "hiTriggers".

I tried the following:

```
for(var i; i < hiTriggers.length; i++) {
    console.log(hiTriggers[i]); // simply to know if it checked them through)
    if(message.indexOf(hiTriggers[i]) >= 0) {
    //do stuff here
}
}
```

Which sadly did not work as I wanted as it does not check at all.
Thanks in advance and I hope I made sense with my post!

Edit; please note that I have 'messaged' already 'declared' at another place.

Comment: Can the hiTriggers be turned into a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)? If so, then you could check to see whether the message matches the expression.

Comment: Depends on how you mean?

Comment: can you show what data is existing in your `message` array?

Comment: What is `message`? You probably want to do `var i = 0` too.

Comment: @Andy - 'message' is something that is sent to the function when it's called, or however I would explain it. It's sent to it when someone sends a message to the bot.

Comment: @WoopWoopWoopWoop I've tried to explain the idea more in the answer below. I'm assuming that message is a string, rather than an array.

Comment: `if (new RegExp('\\b(' + hiTriggers.join('|') + ')\\b', 'i').test(message)) {` possibly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't run because you didn't give the `i` variable an initial value. It is `undefined`.

Change to use `var i=0;`:

```
for(var i=0; i < hiTriggers.length; i++) {
    //console.log(hiTriggers[i]); // simply to know if it checked them through)
    if(message.indexOf(hiTriggers[i]) >= 0) {
        //do stuff here
        console.log("found " + hiTriggers[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, thought it'd be set to 0 as default, didn't think of that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to match the message. The `\b` is a word boundary marker, and the words between the `|` characters are what is being searched for. If any of the words appear in the message, then message.match will return the array of matches, otherwise `null`.

```
var pattern = /\b(Hello|Hi|Hiya)\b/i;
var message = "Hello World";
if (message.match(pattern))
{
    console.log("do stuff");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write even simpler using a `for in` loop:

```
for(var v in hiTriggers){
    if(message.indexOf(hiTriggers[v]) >= 0) {
        //do stuff here
        console.log("found " + hiTriggers[v]);
    }
}
```

Comment: ref: [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

Comment: @Yoshi That problem does not occur in his case. You shouldn't avoid some language feature just because it isn't best practice in each and every case.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is becoz - you have not initialized your var i, make it `var i = 0;`

You can try forEach loop.

```
hiTriggers.forEach(function(e) {

  if(message.indexOf(e) >= 0) {
   //do sthg here
  }
})
```